# How to properly interrupt a process when using 'ssh address executable'?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

To test my program on a remote host I run command:`ssh address ./my_executable`.
The `my_executable` is a long running program but during development I often interrupt it using CTRL+C.
The issue is that CTRL+C interrupts ssh session without killing my process so when I try to run it again I have an error because my process still use resources.

Currently I'm using a workaround:
`ssh address ./my_executable; echo DONE; ssh address pkill my_executable`

But is there a better way to interrupt a program executed through ssh in command mode?

The problem doesn't occur of course when I log in with `ssh address` and run the executable then because signals are passed to remote terminal but it requires more typing and it can't be automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tell `ssh` to explicitly use a terminal, even though it doesn’t need one, you’ll get the behaviour you want:

```
ssh -t address ./my_executable
```

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will kill `my_executable`, not `ssh` (which will exit immediately anyway, because the connection is closed when `my_executable` exits).